# Angular conditional validations

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am using mat form field in my angular form and my code for one of my attribute is as follows.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>CountryCode</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="CountryCode" matInput (click)='updateFormTextValue("alphanumericNext", "CountryCode")'>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to add validation for this field such that if the country is Canada, I want to do Validators.required and Validators.maxLength(30) and if country is other than Canada I just need to check the max length. How can  I do that?

My code in service class is as follows

```
CountryCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]),
```

I am able to use validators provided by angular as my code above but don't know how to put validation as per conditions. I saw some examples on StackOverflow but didn't get how to do it.

PS: country for which I need to put check is one of the fields in my form and its code is same as CountryCode as mentioned above. Please help

Also, need to show the message that if the max length exceeds then message "maximum length exceeded should be shown" and if the field is empty and if the country is Canada then the message "field is required is shown"

Comment: you can use custom validators 
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a **custom validator**.

Something like this:

`CountryCode: new FormControl('', [CountryCodeValidator('Canada')]),`

```
function CountryCodeValidator(countryName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    if (countryName == "Canada") {
      if (control.value.length >= 30) {
        return null
      } else {
        return { 'CountryCode': true };
      }
    } else {
      return null
    }
  };
}
```

Read more about this [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular)

Comment: where do I need to add this code. in my component or in service class where I have defined formgroup and added vlaidations?

Comment: also how I can get required messages?

Comment: Check the modified answer, if it is not valid, you can display a messageby keeping it in a block with *ngIf

Comment: I understood your code. But not getting how to display required message conditionally  using *ngIf. could you please give example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on country selection update validators
 let's assume you select country as "India" `selectedCountry="India"`

```
  if(selectedCountry===India'){
    this.myForm.controls.get('CountryCode').setValidators([Validators.required, 
                                              Validators.maxLength(5)]);
}else{
 this.myForm.controls.get('CountryCode').setValidators([Validators.required, 
                                              Validators.maxLength(4)]);
}
```

you can replace `maxLength(4)` with your country character length.

Comment: do I need to add this to my component? DO I need to change anything in my html code or service code which contains formgroup and validators?